# typescript function overriding with higher order functions

Tags: typescript, fp-ts

I'm confused by this code:

```
/**
 * Lift a function of one argument to a function which accepts and returns values wrapped with the type constructor `F`
 */
export function lift<F extends URIS3>(
  F: Functor3<F>
): <A, B>(f: (a: A) => B) => <U, L>(fa: Type3<F, U, L, A>) => Type3<F, U, L, B>
export function lift<F extends URIS3, U, L>(
  F: Functor3C<F, U, L>
): <A, B>(f: (a: A) => B) => (fa: Type3<F, U, L, A>) => Type3<F, U, L, B>
export function lift<F extends URIS2>(
  F: Functor2<F>
): <A, B>(f: (a: A) => B) => <L>(fa: Type2<F, L, A>) => Type2<F, L, B>
export function lift<F extends URIS2, L>(
  F: Functor2C<F, L>
): <A, B>(f: (a: A) => B) => (fa: Type2<F, L, A>) => Type2<F, L, B>
export function lift<F extends URIS>(F: Functor1<F>): <A, B>(f: (a: A) => B) => (fa: Type<F, A>) => Type<F, B>
export function lift<F>(F: Functor<F>): <A, B>(f: (a: A) => B) => (fa: HKT<F, A>) => HKT<F, B>
/**
 * Lift a function of one argument to a function which accepts and returns values wrapped with the type constructor `F`
 * @function
 */
export function lift<F>(F: Functor<F>): <A, B>(f: (a: A) => B) => (fa: HKT<F, A>) => HKT<F, B> {
  return f => fa => F.map(fa, f)
}
```

I found this in the `fp=ts` [repo](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/master/src/Functor.ts#L95)

I am fairly confused by this.  the initial signature looks the same for each function `<A, B>(f: (a: A) => B)`.

how is typescript determining which is the correct invocation?

Comment: Is not that "<A, B>(f: (a: A) => B)...." the return types? 
Maybe I mistake in this context but I see that different functions require different arguments or number of those if you consider only before the "two points" ':'. Sorry if what I say mean nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about `fp-ts`, but presumably the `lift()` overload is chosen according to whether the `F` argument passed in is a `Functor3<>`, `Functor3C<>`, `Functor2<>` or `Functor2C<>`.  Which I assume are different enough to allow the compiler to pick one.

As @Sam mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49181037/typescript-function-overriding-with-higher-order-functions/49181599#comment85367956_49181037), you seem to be looking at the *return type* of `lift()`, which doesn't enter in to the equation for which overload is chosen.  `lift()` returns another function, which might be confusing you?

Hope that helps.

Comment: so ts does not base overloading on the number of arguments?

Comment: It bases it on the number *and type* of arguments.

Comment: thank you.  I missed the function type.  Lot of crazy shenanigans going on here.

Answer (score 0):

(f: (a: A) => B) uses generic typings in defenition.

You can read more here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Comment: I know what generics are the initial function has the same generic types `<A, B>(f: (a: A) => B)`